# ASPIRED followed by the gerund or the infinitive?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

What follows the verb ASPIRE?

> 1 BACK IN ENGLAND HE **ASPIRED BECOMING** AN ARTIST.
>
> 2 BACK IN ENGLAND HE **ASPIRED TO BECOME** AN ARTIST.

Answer (score 1):

Aspire takes a to-infinitive clause, not an -ing clause.

The iWeb corpus has 2547 hits for "ASPIRE to become", vs 1 hit for "ASPIRE becoming".